What localized label with wireui/wireui is rendered invalidly?
In laravel 11 / livewire 3.5 app I have installed wireui/wireui: ^2.0.5 and using it with multilanguage support
<x-input
    wire:model.live="form.author_name"
    :label="Str::ucfirst(__('partnership_order.author_name'))"
    :placeholder="Str::ucfirst(__('partnership_order.fill_valid_name'))"
    maxlength="255"
    tabindex="10"
    corner="Ex: John Doe"
/>

I ukrainian locale in file lang/ua/partnership_order.php I have :
'author_name' => 'ваше ім\'я',
...
'fill_valid_name' => 'введіть дійсне ім\'я',

But on the screen it is rendered as :


I wonder why the first author_name labelk is rendered incorrectly ?
